# Does Evil Natural Water distinguishes between enemies and allies?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the manga, (spoilers)

> Evil Natural Water attacks the monster who released him from the tank he was in

Does Evil Natural Water distinguishes between enemies and allies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Evil Natural Water does NOT distinguish between enemies and allies.**

ENW is attracted by negative thoughts and fighting intent. It will target and murder anyone in its general vicinity who displays strong negative energy, focusing on the most negative person.

ENW does seem smarter in the manga, as it used the piranhas within its body to attack Child Emperor. Manga!ENW may be smarter and more refined than its webcomic counter-part, but nothing indicates he chooses his targets differently.